# Onclick Function for Kendo MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to work on updating some code for a mobile web app, and I'm having difficulty getting a button to cause a pop-up as it should. I have the following (relevant) code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MobileButton().Name("DropoffDone").Text("Confirm Dropoff").Url("ConfirmDropoff", "Drop", new {id = Model.DeliveryLocationId}).Events(ev => ev.Click("onClick")))
```

and, later in the same file under  tags:

```
    function onClick(ev) {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var minuteToday = currentDate.getHours*60 + currentDate.getMinutes;
        var minuteDeliv = @Model.DropTime.Hour*60 + @Model.DropTime.Minute;
        var difference  = minuteDeliv-minuteToday;
        var r = false;
        if(difference>15){
            r = confirm("Message Here");
            if(!r){
                ev.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
```

The button works fine and it seems to call the javaScript (I tested with a sample alert) but it never seems to actually get to the inside of the 'if' statement. I would like it to pop up with a confirm message, allowing the user to cancel the action. Where is the code not functioning properly? Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: *"while the button works fine, when I click it, it completely ignores the JavaScript"* can't get it, the event `onClick` is being called or not?

Comment: I edited the document for clarity with regards to this.

Comment: What is the value of `difference` when you reach the `if` statement?

Comment: I can't get to it because it's in a view, so the breakpoints don't work (tell me if there is a way to get them to work, that would be awesome!)

Comment: Javascript's [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) should work.

Comment: if you add an `ev.preventDefault()` on the first line of your JS `onClick()` method, does it behave as expected?